# Missing argument label 'coder:' in call when calling NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add an extension to `Float` to convert to `String` with a certain fraction digits. This is the code:

```
extension Float {
    func toString(withFractionDigits: Int) -> String {

        let nf = NumberFormatter()
        nf.numberStyle = .decimal
        nf.minimumFractionDigits = withFractionDigits
        nf.maximumFractionDigits = withFractionDigits

        guard let returnVal = nf.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) else {
            return ""
        }

        return returnVal
    }
}
```

Now, I have an error in the `let nf = NumberFormatter()` line that says this:

> Missing argument label 'coder:' in call

When I searched the web, all that I can find is that the line is actually correct. I don't really have to insert the coder as the parameter. But why did this fail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What XCode version are you using? This compiles just fine for me

Comment: Doesn't your project have another `NumberFormatter`? Please see what happens when you change `let nf = NumberFormatter()` to `let nf = Foundation.NumberFormatter()` .

Comment: Huh. Okay, that's weird. I opened the project again and it worked now. XCode is drunk, apparently. Sorry for the false alarm guys.

Answer (score 0):

Huh. Okay, that's weird. I opened the project again and it worked now. XCode is drunk, apparently. Sorry for the false alarm guys.